# ILMerge and localized resource assemblies

Tags: localization, resources, assemblies, ilmerge, satellite-assembly

We have an application whose structure when compiled looks something like this:

- *Foo*

  - *nb-NO*

    - Text.resources.dll
  - *sv-SE*

    - Text.resources.dll
  - Bar.dll
  - Foo.exe
  - Text.dll

Is it possible to use ILMerge on this? How would you do that?

Answer (score 7):

I asked my own variant of this question and eventually got/implemented an answer: 
[Single-assembly multi-language Windows Forms deployment (ILMerge and satellite assemblies / localization) - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-winforms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-assembl)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes Dotfuscator.

There may be other alternatives out there that I am not aware of but I am pretty sure ILMerge does not do this.

An alternative would be to use Dotfuscator Pro, a commercial product that I know for certain will correctly link together assemblies and does correctly link any satellite resource assemblies for the set of input assemblies.  A free trial is available so that you can test it out and make sure it works in your specific scenario.

Comment: Technical support for dotfuscator says this is not supported.

Comment: Dotfuscator won't merge localized resources for the same assembly for different resources. It *will* merge localized resources for different assemblies that are merged together.

DISCLAIMER: PreEmptive Solutions Employee

Answer (score 0):

[According to one of the comments here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx), if you're willing to give up intellisense, or perhaps maintain separate parallel msbuild files, you can make your DLLs "netmodules" This 0f course assumes you have the source code to your DLLs.