# How to embed language resources into the main exe file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

In a form I set the "Localizable" property to true and added a new language resource by selecting a language in the "Language" property - but...
Then the VS 2008 creates another dll file for the resource
I checked so the "build action" property of the resource is set to "Embedded Resource"

Why the VS do that? and what can be done about it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found here
[Single-assembly multi-language Windows Forms deployment (ILMerge and satellite assemblies / localization) - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-winforms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-assembl)