# How to embed localizations in .NET assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, resources, localization

I created a .NET class library in C# with some resources for localization and already translated them to different languages and put them into different *.resx-files.
But when I compile the assembly, only the default *.resx-files are compiled into the resulting dll and the others are compiled into different dlls in different sub folders.

I know this is the default behavior of Visual Studio but for me this is not very useful, because I do not want to distribute many files in many folders but just one independent dll.

So I need to know what I have to change to compile everything into one dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[IL Merge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)** to combine multiple assemblies into one .dll file.

Comment: I know about this tool, but I thought there had to be an easier way of doing this and I do not want to rely on some external tool but rather use Visual Studio if possible.

Comment: Additionally the ´ResourceManager´ does not find resources that are merged with IL Merge

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way. You can solve the problem with `ResourceManager` fallback as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-windows-forms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-as/1955060#1955060

Comment: @Karsten: This is probably the easiest way. I doubt having to embed your files **manually** and override Assembly resolving method by your own is easier...

Comment: Ended up using IL Merge and using it with [this trick](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx) to automate merging in my build process.