# WinForm Localization folder to a sub directory

Tags: c#, localization

I am localizing a Windows Forms App written in C#, When I localize my app to different languages.
Visual studio creates folder for each language like

\es-ES

\fr-FR etc

I would like to avoid this, because in my situation the app is present on user's drive root C:\ or E:\ etc
I don't want to pollute the user's drive. I can however create one sub folder and let all the garbage go there.

Please advise how can I go about this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to get one single deployable file. How to use ILMerge with satelite assemblies is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-windows-forms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-a).

Comment: Thannks, I already have a sub folder from where my app uses other third party assemblies and other storage related files, I have seen the method above which is a bit of a hack. I would prefer getting them to my sub folder..