# Merge .exe with localization dll's

Tags: c#, dll, merge, .net-4.5

I have c# forms application which uses a bunch of .resx files for licalization. They are named 
myproject\localization\mystring.da-DK.resx, myprogram\localization\mystring.fr-FR.resx and so on.

When i compile the program, the resx files are converted to dll files an placed in folders like this:
bin\da-DK\myprogram.resources.dll

How do i merge these .dll files into the myprogram.exe file?

I have tried using ILMerge with the following command: 
`"ILMerge.exe" /log:"c:\temp\log.txt" "c:\temp\nctoolbar\NCToolbar.exe" "c:\temp\nctoolbar\da-dk\NCToolbar.resources.dll" "c:\temp\nctoolbar\HtmlAgilityPack.dll" /out:"c:\temp\Merged.exe" /targetplatform:v4 /lib:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5"` 
This seems to work for the HtmlAgilityPack.dll but not the localization file.

[Single-assembly multi-language Windows Forms deployment (ILMerge and satellite assemblies / localization) - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-windows-forms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-a) this link talks about System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager but i don't see that i my XXX.Designer.cs. I am using 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never! I hope you solved your issue, but next time, think about this helpful tool to accomplish this: [ILMerge-GUI](https://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/). Is very easy and fast.