# How can I use dotfuscator to merge multiple localization files?

Tags: .net, dotfuscator

According to a post from a user on this question:

[ILMerge and localized resource assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613407/ilmerge-and-localized-resource-assemblies)

You can use dotfuscator to do this. I'd like to, because I'm having issues with ILmerge. But when I try to add all my resource.dlls for localization and combine them with my exe, I get the following error:

```
An assembly appears more than once in the input list.  This version of Dotfuscator does not support side by side versioned assemblies as inputs. (Gatherer.resources.dll)
Build Error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted dotfuscator support and their technician said the developer was incorrect and it does not support that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Dotfuscator won't merge localized resources for the same assembly for different resources. It *will* merge localized resources for different assemblies that are merged together.

Given the way the framework looks up localized resources in satellite assemblies, I'm not sure there is any other alternative other than writing custom code to do your own language string substitution.

DISCLAIMER: PreEmptive Solutions Employee